# Gronwall constant = 0

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Gronwall's inequality states that if $$f(t) \leq a+\int\limits_{0}^t B(s)f(s)\text{d}s$$ for some constant function $a$, then $$f(t) \leq a \text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s.$$  I am wondering: what happens if $a=0$ but $B(s)$ is unbounded?  Then, $\text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s$ would be infinitely large, so would $a \text{ exp}\int\limits_{0}^t B(s) \text{d}s$ be $0$ or something else?

Comment: But, $t$ is fixed and finite.

Comment: Gronwalls in fact usually gives you only an exponential bound in time